# StateListDrawable not working in API 10

Tags: android

Hi I have the following StateListDrawable

```
    StateListDrawable circles = new StateListDrawable();
    circles.addState(View.SELECTED_STATE_SET, filledCircle());
    circles.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, circle());
```

In Android API 18 - this works correctly - i.e. A circle normally, or a filled circle if the item is selected. In API 10 - it doesn't work at all - I only see a circle even though the elements state is updated correctly.

Any ideas what changed in the API? 
The rest of the code is based on the PageIndicator in GreenDroid - so I'm assuming it's just this bit that I implemented.

Comment: your StateListDrawable seems to be fine, i'd suggest checking filledCircle() and circle() for anything that was introduced after API10 (maybe just use two ColorDrawables for testing)

Comment: circle & filledCircle work fine - I've dropped the StateListDrawable while I find the bug and just manually switch between the two and both render ok :-)

Comment: Are you setting the statelistdrawables later to the view?

Comment: There's no change in this class since API-3.

Comment: Yes - I'm seeing the unselected state always. Changing the state of the drawable to selected doesn't cause the filledCircle to draw.